# how to display error same laybsmodal window when raising error

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, blazor-server-side

I use a blazor and a blazorstrap.
Usually, when the server becomes disconect, "Error" is displayed.
However, when the BsModal of the blazer strap is displayed, it is displayed in the lower layer.
Therefore, it cannot be operated. How can I display it?
Or is it possible to cancel BsModal when this happens?

_Host.cshtml

```
<div id="components-reconnect-modal" class="my-reconnect-modal components-reconnect-hide">
    <div class="show">
        <p>
            attempting to connect to server
        </p>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    </div>
    <div class="failed">
        <p>
            failing to connect
        </p>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rejected">
        <p>
            refused
        </p>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    </div>
</div>
<app>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</app>
<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    <environment include="Staging,Production">
        An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
    </environment>
    <environment include="Development">
        An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
    </environment>
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
```

[referenced here](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/general/how-can-i-show-a-custom-message-when-a-customers-connection-is-lost-with-the-server)

modals.razor

```html
@page "/modals"
@using BlazorStrap
<h1>Modals</h1>

<h3>Live Demo</h3>
<h3>Vertically Centered</h3>
<div class="docs-example">
    <BSButton Color="Color.Primary" @onclick="@onToggle">Launch demo modal</BSButton>
    <BSModal @ref="VerticallyCentered" IsCentered="true">
        <BSModalHeader OnClick="@onToggle">Modal title</BSModalHeader>
        <BSModalBody><p>Modal body text goes here.</p></BSModalBody>
        <BSModalFooter>
            <BSButton Color="Color.Secondary" @onclick="@onToggle">Close</BSButton>
            <BSButton Color="Color.Primary" @onclick="@onToggle">Save Changes</BSButton>
        </BSModalFooter>
    </BSModal>
</div>

@code { BSModal VerticallyCentered { get; set; }

    bool IsOpen { get; set; }
    void onToggle(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        VerticallyCentered.Toggle();
    }
    void OpenChenged(bool b)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(b);
    } }
```

[nomaly error display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uMsc.png)

[Error is displayed under layer of modal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPYFM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try two different approaches:

Just move

```
<div id="blazor-error-ui">
</div>
```

above of

```
<div id="components-reconnect-modal"...>
</div>
```

Or try assinging each of this layers (divs) a different z-index on their styles or clases:

```
<div id="blazor-error-ui" style="z-index:9999" >
```

or, in the css file on the rule #blazor-error-ui { ....; z-index: 9999 }

and, if neccessary, add a lower z-index number to the "components-reconnect-modal"

Comment: I solved it by the method you taught me.
The problem was just "z-index".
Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help you! Could you please mark the answer as valid?